# boost::bind, std::bind and overloaded functions

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-bind

I noticed that boost::bind, unlike std::bind, can work with overloaded functions when one of these functions doesn't have any parameters. Am I right? Is this documented?

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "::foo() \n";
}

void foo(int)
{
    std::cout << "::foo(int) \n";
}

int main()
{
    boost::bind(foo)(); // Ok
    boost::bind(foo, 0)(); // Ok

    // std::bind(foo)(); // Error
    // std::bind(foo, 0)(); // Error
}

#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void foo(int)
{
    std::cout << "::foo(int) \n";
}

void foo(const std::string&)
{
    std::cout << "::foo(const std::string&) \n";
}

int main()
{
    // boost::bind(foo, 0)(); // Error
    // boost::bind(foo, "str")(); // Error

    // std::bind(foo, 0)(); // Error
    // std::bind(foo, "str")(); // Error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would assume it is just an unintended artifact of the implementation details, I don't think Boost provides any guarantees about automatically resolving the correct overload.

`std::bind` is a C++11 feature implemented with variadic templates.

`boost::bind` was implemented for C++03, meaning that it relies on a large number of overloaded function templates.

The two are quite different in their implementation details, and so, I would assume any difference between their behavior is a consequence of that, rather than an intentional and specified difference.

The Boost documentation only states this:
"An attempt to bind an overloaded function *usually* results in an error, as there is no way to tell which overload was meant to be bound."

In my book, this means that Boost docs tell you that it is "undefined behavior" whether or not this will work (compile) or even select the correct overload.

And as far as I know, you should always use an explicit cast (`static_cast`) to fix the signature of the overload that you wish to select. This is true for both `boost::bind` and `std::bind`, and in that sense, both implementations agree.

Answer (score 2):

It is somewhat documented as part of the "Interfaces" -> "Synopsis" part, where the overloads are listed. As you can see there, Boost does *not* use variadic templates, hence when given those overload, explicitly these:

```
template<class R> unspecified-2 bind(R (*f) ());
template<class F, class A1> unspecified-3-1 bind(F f, A1 a1);
template<class R, class B1, class A1> unspecified-4 bind(R (*f) (B1), A1 a1);
```

the compiler prefers the overloaded versions with an empty argument list over others as it is a better match. I don't think this was intentional, though.

Answer (score 1):

The first case compiles well in MSVC10 with both `std` and `boost` (because MSVC10 doesn't support variadic templates, so `std::bind` is implemented similarly to `boost::bind`).

The second case wouldn't compile, because `bind` can resolve overloads having different arity, but can't resolve overloads that differ by argument types only.